# How to find the best words for my sentences?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, phrases, expression-choice

Are there any techniques or web-tools to find the best words to fit your sentence?

For example, I want to find the best verb/phrase to say

> **reply with** a positive feedback

the result would be:

> **give** positive feedback

---

So far I have been using google search operators, like this:

> * positive feedback

OR

> ~reply positive feedback

Comment: Yes. It's called [ell.se] -- it calls for a bit of hard work though. Good Luck.

Comment: There can be no automatic tool for this. You will need actual humans. And yes, anyone can become one such human, but as with everything in life, it takes dedication and time. The only technique here is, stop writing and start reading. Practice that technique many times a day for many years on end. You will know when you've practiced enough. But until then, practice.

Comment: Make a diary/notebook and start recording words or phrases that catch your interest for whatever reason :D

Comment: So far I have been using google search operators, like this:

* positive feedback
OR

~reply positive feedback

Answer (score 2):

Try this online [dictionary of collocations.](http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com)

(Wikipedia defines a [collocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) as "a sequence of words or terms which co-occur more often than would be expected by chance".)